# How do I enable mounting filesystems in docker containers using apparmor

Tags: docker, ubuntu, mount, apparmor

This question was reposted [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/654191).

I have a ubuntu 20.04 server running docker. Recently the default apparmor profile seems to have started enforcing a restriction on mount points in docker containers. So the containers write directly to the root filesystem rather than the mount.

Outside of docker I can navigate the mounts with no issues but when executing a shell in containers it is as if the mount points are not mounted.

I have narrowed this down to being caused by apparmor and disabling apparmor allows mounting and everything works as I would expect. The containers seem to be using the docker-default profile.

My question is: how do I enable mounting in docker container either on a global basis or on individual containers. I would rather not have to completely disable apparmor for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out my issue was actually with Docker starting before filesystems were mounted. I believe I can alter the systemd file for docker to delay starting until my mounts are in place. The containers were binding to the mount point as a directory and writing directly to the root filesystem.

Incidentally you can change the apparmor profile used for containers with the security_opt option and load in a new profile with apparmor-parser. My containers didn't have mount but nor should they need it if the mounts are already in place.